# ES6 + Babel + Gulp + Browserify, Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I'am making a framework using ES6, i'am using babel to transpile code to es5 and browserify/babelify to manage module.

i have an output file bundle.js that i include in a html page. I can't access class or function of my bundle from here (**Uncaught ReferenceError: myTest is not defined**). I don't understand why.

```js
export function myTest() {
    console.log('myTest');
}
```

```js
function babelify() {
  return browserifyAPI({
      entries: '../src/es6/utils/app.js',
      extensions: ['.js'],
      debug: DEBUG
    })
    .transform(babelifyAPI)
    .bundle()
    .on("error", function(err) {
      console.log("Error : " + err.message);
    })
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'));
}

gulp.task(TASK_NAME_BABELIFY, [TASK_NAME_CODE_STYLE_CHECKER, TASK_NAME_CODE_ANALYSIS], function() {
  var bundle = babelify();
  bundle.pipe(gulp.dest(OUTPUT_RELEASE_PATH));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="../../build/release/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
(function testECS() {
    myTest();
})();
```

Generated bundle.js

```js
(function e(t, n, r) {
  function s(o, u) {
    if (!n[o]) {
      if (!t[o]) {
        var a = typeof require == "function" && require;
        if (!u && a) return a(o, !0);
        if (i) return i(o, !0);
        var f = new Error("Cannot find module '" + o + "'");
        throw f.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", f
      }
      var l = n[o] = {
        exports: {}
      };
      t[o][0].call(l.exports, function(e) {
        var n = t[o][1][e];
        return s(n ? n : e)
      }, l, l.exports, e, t, n, r)
    }
    return n[o].exports
  }
  var i = typeof require == "function" && require;
  for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) s(r[o]);
  return s
})({
  1: [
    function(require, module, exports) {
      'use strict';

      Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
        value: true
      });
      exports.myTest = myTest;

      function myTest() {
        console.log('myTest');
      }

    }, {}
  ]
}, {}, [1])
```

Comment: Seems like you want a "standalone" bundle. Read more about it in the docs: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

Comment: Thx!!!! i added standalone: 'App' in the gulp file in the browserify option and now i can call App.myTest(), thx so much